# Get the Column with the Maximum Same Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
follower | following
2        | 1
3        | 1
1        | 13
13       | 1
2        | 1
24       | 18
24       | 5
5        | 24
```

It contains the usernames of different users following each other. The person being most followed is 1, so I want to display an output like: "Most Followed Person On This Website is 1 Having 4 Followings".

Comment: SELECT MAX(*) FROM <whatever>

Comment: Why is it tagged PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html):

```
SELECT following, COUNT(*) AS followcount
FROM follows
GROUP BY following
ORDER BY followcount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[***Demo***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29484/1/0)

Comment: your alias shouldn't be a keyword... thats a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT following, 
       COUNT(follower) AS followercount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY following
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/197d1c/2)

Comment: the thing is i want only the userid of the person being followed the most,not all users

Comment: Isn't that what this gives you? It should give you a single row returned with the userid of the person with the most followers in `following`, and the count of their followers in `followercount`. With your sample data, it should return `following` of 1 and a `followercount` of 4

Comment: Though your sample data has oddities, because user id 2 is following user id 1 twice

Comment: well,i edited data on random so that 1 was being followed most,so yeah

Comment: +1 very nice and concise query... i like that you aren't referencing an alias in the ORDER BY.. this should be the preferred answer

Comment: Didn't know that you can order by the column number not alias. However, doesn't get my upvote since it was invalid and edited after my answer...